# Symfony decrementing on an action

Tags: php, symfony

I'm coming to you for help, please, I do not know how to do it.

Basically for each case who are respect : if 'amout' 'training' et ''objectif' are > or = a 100 
in this case I have to decrement the number of 'remaining seats'.

acutelement mon code ressemble a cela :

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$company = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Company')->find($user->getCompany());
$league = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:League')->find($user->getCompany()->getLeague());
$remainingSeats = $league->getRemainingSeats() ;

if (!$user->isAcceptTC() && !$this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('terms');
}

if ($company->getAmout() >= 100
    && $company->getTraining() >= 100
    && $company->getAmountXObjective() >= 100) {
    while ($remainingSeats >= 0) {
        --$remainingSeats;
        break;
    }

    $league->setRemainingSeats($remainingSeats);
    $em->persist($league);
    $em->flush();
}
```

I know that my code is not good or not logical, basically on my code every time I update it decreases while I am sorry that it decreases only once.

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: I think `while ($remainingSeats >= 0) {` should be `if ($remainingSeats >= 0) {` otherwise a while loop will decrement the remainingseats to Zero each time

Comment: _in this case I have to decrement the number of 'remaining seats'._ Decrement by ONE or zeroise the remaining seats? Your question is not clear

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you , sorry my english is not realy good, i wanted to say if all these condition are good i want Decrement on 'Remaining seats' and stop the action

Comment: So you mean if all condition are met, you will set remainingseats to zero?

Comment: @RiggsFolly not really, exemple: if Remaining seats is 5 and the condition are met i want Remaining seats become only 4 and stop. but now 
when I refresh the page ma contition is always valid so she decrement until 0

Comment: So as per comment 1. Replace the WHILE LOOP with a simple IF

Comment: And test should probably be `if ($remainingSeats >= 1) {` so you dont end up with a negative number

Comment: Your question is unclear, but $remainingSeats decreases only once, because you put a `break` into loop